# Windows 2008 R2 | DFS Replication skipping certain files & permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

We have universal namespace, i.e. us.company.###.com and within that we have DFS shares set as
\us.company.###.com\company

We've recently notice certain directories are not replicating correctly. The directories have the exact same security and sharing set up, and the only change in the DFS environment is we're reaching close to 90% disk utilization on that share.

So far we've been manually using a DIFF tool when this comes up, however I'd like to get to the bottom of why this is happening.

In troubleshooting I've run a couple of the DFRSDIAG commands and everything seems to be working correctly.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

You give very little details of what the issue/symptoms are and what steps you've taken to troubleshoot. So all I can suggest is the following link which will help you read and analyse the DFSR debug logs. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/09/dfsr-debug-log-series-wrapup-and-downloadable-copies.aspx

HTH